# How to print new line in HTML format using echo command in shell script

Tags: html, css, shell

Here is my requirement.

```
$ cat 123.log

ebspdv1START
Patch description:  "OJVM PATCH SET UPDATE 11.2.0.4.171017"
Patch description:  "OCW PATCH SET UPDATE: 11.2.0.4.180417 (27441052)"
Patch description:  "DATABASE PATCH FOR EXADATA (Apr 2018 - 11.2.0.4.180417) : (27346006)"
ebspdv1END

$ Iname=ebspdv1
$ ora_inst_home=/bio/vcp/ppt/db/11.2.0.4
echo "<TR><TD class='dbcc'>Main Patch info of <B>$Iname: $ora_inst_home</B></TD><TD class='dbcnc'>`cat 123.log |sed -n "/^${Iname}START\$/,/^${Iname}END\$/p"|grep -v $Iname|cut -d: -f2-3|sed 's/\"//g'`</TD></TR>" >>123.html
```

Present Output in HTML:

```
Main Patch info of ebspdv1: /bio/vcp/ppt/db/11.2.0.4    OJVM PATCH SET UPDATE 11.2.0.4.171017 OCW PATCH SET UPDATE: 11.2.0.4.180417 (27441052) DATABASE PATCH FOR EXADATA (Apr 2018 - 11.2.0.4.180417) : (27346006)
```

Expected Output in HTML (each value should print in new line):

```
Main Patch info of ebspdv1: /bio/vcp/ppt/db/11.2.0.4    OJVM PATCH SET UPDATE 11.2.0.4.171017 
                                                        OCW PATCH SET UPDATE: 11.2.0.4.180417 (27441052) 
                                                        DATABASE PATCH FOR EXADATA (Apr 2018 - 11.2.0.4.180417) : (27346006)
```

Current HTML output:

[image: Present HTML Output screenshot]

Comment: Add <br> tag between lines inside your <td>.

Answer (score 0):

The pipeline to extract the patch info can be written entirely in one sed call:

```
sed -n "/^${Iname}START\$/,/^${Iname}END\$/ {
    /^$Iname/d
    s/^[^\"]\+\"//
    s/\"$/<br\/>/
    p
}" 123.log
```

or awk, which may be more readable depending on your taste:

```
awk -v iname="$Iname" '
    BEGIN                {FS = "\""; ORS = "<BR/>\n"}
    $0 ~ "^"iname"END"   {p = 0}
    p                    {print $2}
    $0 ~ "^"iname"START" {p = 1}
' 123.log
```

Then, I'd put the HTML in a heredoc for readability:

```
patch_info=$(
    sed -n "/^${Iname}START\$/,/^${Iname}END\$/ {
        /$Iname/d
        s/^[^\"]\+\"//
        s/\"$/<br\/>/
        p
    }" 123.log
)
cat <<HTML >>123.html
<TR>
<TD class='dbcc'>Main Patch info of <B>$Iname: $ora_inst_home</B></TD>
<TD class='dbcnc'>$patch_info</TD>
</TR>
HTML
```

Comment: I really appreciate  your response. I just tried with you inputs. Here is the result.

Comment: $ patch_info=$(
>     sed -n "/^${Iname}START\$/,/^${Iname}END\$/ {
>         /$Iname/d
>         s/^[^\"]\+\"//
>         s/\"$/<br\/>/
>         p
>     }" 123.log
>
>
> ^C
$ echo $patch_info

$

Am i missing anything here.

Comment: did you define a value for `$Iname`?